# passing a parameter to bash operator - what has changed?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have code that is calling python notebook execution from the bash operator.
The code used to run with no issues with older composer and airflow versions. I have updated the environment to include python to 3 and the latest composer and airflow releases. 
The parameters are not available for the notebook at the environemnt variable as it used to be. this is the code that used to work:

```
# before the DAG description:
rna_cmd_1 = "runipy " + RNA_STEP_1_NB_PATH. #executing ipynb in the DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
Variable.set("BUCKET_URL","gs://path/to/bucket")
# in the DAG description
with models.DAG(....
  BUCKET_URL = Variable.get("BUCKET_URL")
  prefix_args_bash = "BUCKET_URL"+BUCKET_URL+" "

  bash_rna_cmd_1=prefix_args_bash+rna_cmd_1
  run_step1 = bash.operator.BashOperator(task_id='task-id',bash_command=bash_rna_cmd_1)
```

In the ipynb (python notebook), I called the following code to get the parameter value:

```
from os import environ
BUCKET_URL = environ['BUCKET_URL']
```

What has changed from the previous versions? what is the right way to extract the parameters? I can always pass the parameters within a text file but wanted to avoid that solution.

any idea on ways to pass parameters to ipynb using bash operator?

Thanks,
eilalan

Comment: What are your current Composer and Airflow image versions?

Comment: Image version:
composer-1.10.3-airflow-1.10.6

Comment: Looking at the variable view, I see that the variable was not assigned. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the official Airflow [Bash_Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html#bashoperator) guidelines, I guess you might be able to fetch the user Airflow metadata (key/value data) that was defined throughout `Variable.set()` function within `var` template variable leveraging [Jinga template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#jinja-templating) methods.

For instance, you can refer to `BUCKET_URL` variable in `bash_command` parameter, explicitly mapping environment variables for the new process to the template variable:

```
from airflow.models import Variable

Variable.set("BUCKET_URL","gs://path/to/bucket")

....

with models.DAG(

    ...

    print_bucket_url = bash_operator.BashOperator(
            task_id="print_task",
            bash_command="echo {{ var.value.BUCKET_URL }}"
    )

    print_bucket_url
```